# onUserAfterSave called twice because of addUserToGroup

Tags: php, plugin

The process of registration is taking way too long (22 secs) so I've been profiling the plugin execution to see what is happening. My registration process is something I do with a custom component (for mobile registration). I've also got a couple of plugins that are fired with `onUserAfterSave` and a third custom plugin. So I though the problem was with my plugins but they seem pretty quick. What is slow is the time between and the fact that my plugins are called twice. This is the execution flow:

> 2014-05-06T18:39:50+00:00       INFO    -       mobileregister..START
>   Joomla save
>
> 2014-05-06T18:39:56+00:00       INFO    -       Start of
>   onUserAfterSave in RegRedirect 2014-05-06T18:39:56+00:00       INFO
>   2014-05-06T18:40:02+00:00       INFO    -       Start of
>   onUserAfterSave in RegRedirect 2014-05-06T18:40:02+00:00       INFO
>   -       End of onUserAfterSave in RegRedirect
>
> 2014-05-06T18:40:02+00:00       INFO    -       ResetToken START -
>   onUserAfterSave 2014-05-06T18:40:02+00:00       INFO    -
>   ResetToken END - onUserAfterSave
>
> 2014-05-06T18:40:11+00:00       INFO    -       ResetToken START -
>   onUserAfterSave 2014-05-06T18:40:11+00:00       INFO    -
>   ResetToken END - onUserAfterSave
>
> 2014-05-06T18:40:12+00:00       INFO    -       mobileregister..END
>   Joomla save

My plugins RegRedirect and ResetToken are being called twice (not SetLimits). The time between that is several seconds. Any ideas on what I can do to figure out what is going on?

**EDIT:**

I have a bit more clues of what is going on. It seems the code to add a user to a group triggers all the onUserAfterSave events again. This is the code I have in RegRedirect.

```
JUserHelper::addUserToGroup($user['id'], $service_provider["usergroup_id"]);
```

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Are you sure you have two events running? For example it would appear that in your supplied info there is only 1 end ```End of onUserAfterSave in RegRedirect``` so I'm wondering if it's more something odd with your log dumps?

Comment: @GeorgeWilson Not 100% sure but I don't see anything wrong with the logging. It is odd that there is only 1 `End of onUserAfterSave in RegRedirect`. You can also see that there are 2 `ResetToken` plugins called as well. Very confused...

Comment: Can you not add the correct usergroup when creating the user?

Comment: @GeorgeWilson What do you mean? That's what I'm doing. I'm adding a user to the correct usergroup. The problem is that using `addUserToGroup` then launches all the `onUserAfterSave` events again. Makes sense but it is duplicating things. Seems like a good practice is to never use `addUserToGroup` in `onUserAfterSave`. I need to figure out how to add a user to a group during registration without `addUserToGroup`.

Comment: Ahh okay right this makes more sense now if you're adding the user to group in the plugin. I would advise doing a cursory check on the user to see if he's new. If so abort in the plugin early. I don't think you can really avoid running the plugin twice

Comment: This is _way_ too long, try to give us more info: is the database local? what rendering time are you getting on the "normal" pages? is this delay consistent or does it vary? where are you storing sessions? And most importantly, if you make a copy of the site on your development machine or on another host, are the times still so long? what extensions do you have installed? which plugins are enabled? are you using cache? what hosting plan are you using? are you hosting 500 sites on a 5$/month plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've found one solution. This works for my mobile registration but won't work for typical registration. I wonder how many people realize that this call:

```
JUserHelper::addUserToGroup($user_id, $group_id);
```

will execute the `onUserAfterSave` event again. I've seen numerous posts with this recommendation. In terms of registration this is not what you want. But Joomla is not at fault here. It correctly recognizes you are changing the user by adding them to a group so it triggers the `onUserAfterSave`.

To get around this for my mobile registration I basically just do what the current registration component does:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser(0);
jimport('joomla.application.component.helper');
$usersParams = &JComponentHelper::getParams( 'com_users' );
$userdata = array();
//pull in other user data during registration...        
$defaultUserGroup = $usersParams->get('new_usertype', 2);
//here you need to add your usergroup id
$userdata['groups']=array($defaultUserGroup, $usergroup_id);
```

A different way to do the same thing. Works for me and has made my registration almost twice as fast. Web registration is also a problem but I haven't found a way around that (I don't have the usergroup id available like I do in mobile registration).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you wrap your code around `if (!$isNew) { ... }`

The first call to `public function onUserAfterSave($data, $isNew, $result, $error) {}` will set `$isNew` to `true` but the second call that sets the group will set it to `false`.

And when it is set to `false`, that means that the account is most likely settled.